# What function should I use beside sum for summing values of certain number of documents registered in the DB?

Tags: mysql, database, function, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have to do a client based statistic report in which I include, in the first column, count of clients which have 1 to 50 registered documents, then 51 to 100 documents..and so on to 901 to 1000 documents. or this I used this expression "Sum(IIF(Fields!Calculated_Value_03.Value>0 AND Fields!Calculated_Value_03.Value<=50, 1, 0))" where calculated_value_03 is the number of documents per client and it worked. The next step is to bring in the second column the invoiced value for each category of clients(for 1 to 50, 51 to 100..etc) and i used this expression "sum(IIF(Fields!Calculated_Value_03.Value>0 AND Fields!Calculated_Value_03.Value<=50, Fields!Calculated_Value_09.Value, 0))" where Calculate_Value_09 is the net invoiced value, but those conditions are both true and the expression is summing everything in the DB. Any clue on how i could solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try to put more efforts into formatting your question properly.

Comment: I'll consider that on the future